# crash at [FBSDKInternalUtility validateFacebookReservedURLSchemes]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

Currently I have updated Facebook ios sdk framework to v4.11.0. I'm Using Xcode 7.3 and deployment target is 7.0 with latest ios base sdk 9.3. My app compile successfully but it crashes in splash screen. I have added screenshots below:

[image]

Comment: enable zombies and try

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have already  enabled zombies

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It is directly jumping in to assembly not showing in code

Comment: check once line no 93 , are you added the lsapplicationqueryschema's in plist

Answer (score 5):

I've run into the same problem and the secret of the solution is in the red text above. Make sure you've added your app ID into the .plist, as instructed in [Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)

When filling in `fb{your-app-id}`, if your app ID is `12345`, make sure you fill in `fb12345`. I've omitted the `fb` part of the string and ended up receiving the same crash as you're reporting.

I know I'm 2 months late, but perhaps someone else finds this helpful.

Z.